# Implementing Dynamic Theme Colors via SCSS Variables

Tags: javascript, angular, themes, angular-cli

I set up a global style scss root color.I wish to modify our ts file's style scss variable. I want to avoid adding any inline styles to the project.
The backend api decides the theme color.
Which methods work best for doing that?
I would like to use a SCSS variable to add many themes.

lobal SCSS Variable: Create a global SCSS variable for the root color in the project's stylesheets. This variable will serve as the base color for the application.

Dynamic Theme Update: Implement a service or utility function that fetches the theme color from the backend API. Upon receiving the color information, dynamically update the global SCSS variable.

SCSS Theme Variables: Define additional SCSS variables for each theme the application supports. These variables should be based on the global root color but with specific adjustments for each theme's color scheme.

Theme Switching: Implement a user interface element (e.g., a dropdown menu) that allows users to select the desired theme. Upon selection, update the global SCSS variable to match the chosen theme's color.

Comment: I really suggest you look into native CSS variables, so your server doesn't even have to do the work of compiling them anymore and all you need to do is load a `:root` style with your base variables.